# Received empty response from Zabbix Agent

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I have zabbix installed on my wan ip and I'm able to add clients in that of same Wan Ip network, But when i'm trying to add a zabbix client of different Wan network range, i'm getting -

> Received empty response from Zabbix Agent at [xx.xx.xx.xx]. Assuming
>   that agent dropped connection because of access permission.

There is no filtering at any end, and i have cross checked zabbix_agentd.conf file may times and found no errors. I can see ports listening at 10050 on client servers.

Comment: can you add your zabbix_agentd.conf file?

Answer (score 1):

The [Troubleshooting page](https://www.zabbix.org/wiki/Troubleshooting#Zabbix_says_.22Agent_unreachable.22.2C_but_the_host_is_up._How_do_I_debug_that.3F) on Zabbix.org is a classical reference for troubleshooting unreachable agents.

In this particular case, you might wish to start with checking that Zabbix server IP is listed in agent's Server configuration parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the above problem. it was my router's wan ip that was collecting the data from zabbix agent and not the zabbix server's wan ip.
so i gave both the ips of my router as well as of zabbix server in zabbix_agentd.conf's Server and ServerActive . and now its working fine.
Thanks